# How to delete rows that cannot join - SQL Query

Tags: sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have a table 1 which contains some data, but specifically two columns 'user' and 'date'

I have another table which contains other data but also has columns 'user' and 'date'.

As you've properly guessed these two tables JOIN on 'user' and 'date'.

Table 1 is constantly being messed with, data, added, edited, deleted etc.

What i want to do is make a query that checks table 2 and if there are any rows that do not join to table one on 'user' and 'date' then to delete that row.

```
    if (sqlite3_open([dbTable2PathString UTF8String], & Table2DB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if (sqlite3_exec(Table2DB, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE \'%s\' AS SECOND", [dbTable1PathString UTF8String]] UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString* deleteQuery = @"DELETE t2 FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.user = t2.user AND t1.date = t2.date where t1.user is NULL";

        sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(Table2DB, [deleteQuery UTF8String], -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt))
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(Table2DB));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(Table2DB));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
    }
}
else
{
    sqlite3_close(Table2DB); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}
```

Ive tried this query before but get the error

```
@"DELETE FROM TABLE2 LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON (TABLE1.user = TABLE2.user AND TABLE1.date= TABLE2.date) where TABLE1.user is 'NULL'"
```

Error:

```
near "LEFT": syntax error
```

Ive tried this query before but get the error

```
@"DELETE t2 FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.user = t2.user AND t1.date = t2.date where t1.user is NULL"
```

Error :

```
near "t2": syntax error
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Answer (score 3):

```
delete t2
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 on t1.user = t2.user and t1.date = t2.date
where t1.user is null
```

Basically you need a `left join` and delete the rows where the join failed.

Comment: You did not apply my query correctly. `delete t2 from table2...`

Comment: And remove the quotes around `NULL`. `NULL` is not the same as `'NULL'` These are totally different things